# protractor binding for angular

Tags: angular, protractor

Setup Protractor v5.2.0, Angular 5
I have tried using `by.binding` & `by.model`, but result in "error angular is undefined".

Question is, Protractor v5 Supports *`by.binding` & `by.model`* ?
if yes, any direction to resolve will be good

Comment: Added backticks to call out code bits for clarity.

Comment: Suggest you add some code to show how and where the error is occurring.